# How do I extract a single list of 3D spatial coordinates across 2 different sheets that link the 3 cartesian planes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, shapes, column, blank

I am using Excel to draw an ellipsoid that is rotated by 15 degrees. What I want is not a 3D plot of it, but I want to get a list of all the coordinates that share a certain criteria. An example is shown below that illustrates this exercise:

[X-Z plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGANo.png)
This figure shows a view of the ellipsoid from the X-Z plane. I am interested in the coordinates where the cell value is "-1" or represented in gray. As an example, let's take X = -436 and Z = 251. This is an instance of a cell that has the value "-1" in it.

[Z-Y plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfqFV.png)
This figure shows a view of the ellipsoid from the Z-Y plane. Given that we have selected Z = 251, there are 2 corresponding Y values, which are Y = 61 and Y = 70.

We will skip the X-Y plane because this is enough information. Combining the above selection with this one, we end up with 2 sets of 3D coordinates;

1. X = -436, Y = 61, Z = 251
2. X = -436, Y = 70, Z = 251

What I would like to do is have, in a separate sheet, a single formula that I can drag down to look at all of the values and list out the sets of X, Y, Z coordinates that I can refer to simply.

What I have tried doing is to use an Index formula that looks at whether or not the value within the column is "-1" ala this video: [Ignore blank cells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDsKEriIIaU&ab_channel=MITutorials)

I did get it to work partially, but then I would need to paste this formula many times over because the values are spread across a 2D array and not a 1D array. Additionally, I could not figure out how to return the X, Y, Z values, instead it returns only "-1"s.

The ideal solution is a singular formula that I can drag down to cover all the situations. I am also open to other solutions such as using PowerBI or other. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have Office 365?

Comment: Seems like knowing the formula for the ellipsoid and desired precision would be enough to "step through" calculating and populating such a table without need for the visualization.